# cache or session in a search form

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, search, pagination, kohana

I'd like to cache my search conditions which collected from a post form.Just like age >20 or gender is male.
Then I can get the search right soon when I click next page if I use a pagination.
But I am puzzled at work in an php mvc framework kohana 3.2.
who can give me a demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `Session` class:

```
Session::instance()->set($key, $value);

$value = Session::instance()->get($key);
if ($value) {
    // do something with the value
}
```

Comment: Of course,I know it.
But just so easy?
thanks all the same.

Comment: Yes, just use `Session::instance()->set` to save your values from one page to another, and `Session::instance()->get` to get them back.